# Location of the Speakableitems.app

Tags: macos

Does anyone know where I can find the speakableitems.app? My aim is to find the location of the resources folder so that I can edit how it looks....

I have been looking for a while and I can't find it :L

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mdfind speakableitems`. It is located at `/System/Library/Speech/Recognizers/AppleSpeakableItems.SpeechRecognizer/Contents/PlugIns/SpeakableItems.app` on my installation of 10.8.